# Find common Keys from two dict and return new dict from common keys

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have two dicts called results and results_2 with different lengths with the following setup:
Result is also significantly shorter than the Result_2:

```
result
{('CMS', 'LNT'): 0.8500276624334894,
 ('LNT', 'CMS'): 0.8500276624334894,
 ('LOW', 'HD'): 0.8502400376842035,
 ('HD', 'LOW'): 0.8502400376842036,
 ('SWKS', 'QRVO'): 0.8507993847326996,
...


result_2
{('CMS', 'CMS'): 1.0,
 ('CMS', 'LNT'): 0.7761431649456381,
 ('CMS', 'LOW'): 0.4476903306386938,
 ('CMS', 'HD'): 0.35617507290738476,
 ('CMS', 'SWKS'): 0.04797167063700858,
 ('CMS', 'QRVO'): -0.08844725271734241,
....
```

Now I want to find all keys which are in both dict and create a new dict with only the duplicate combinations and their values

The Output should look like this:

```
result_combined

{('CMS', 'LNT'): 0.8500276624334894,
 ('CMS', 'LNT'): 0.7761431649456381,
....
```

I have tried using the following code however I am only getting an empty dict:

```
dict_sorted_2 = {}

for key_2, result_2 in results_2.items():
    
    for key, result in results.items():
    
        if key_2 == key:
            dict_sorted[key_2] = result_2
            

abcd = dict(sorted(dict_sorted_2.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
abcd
```

Out[24]: {}

EDIT:

This is the code I am using to get the result dicts

```
results_2 = {}

for ticker1 in data_5d:
    for ticker2 in data_5d:
        if data_5d[ticker1].size == data_5d[ticker2].size:
            corr = np.corrcoef(data_5d[ticker1]['%Percentage'], data_5d[ticker2]['%Percentage'])[0,1]
            print(f"Correlation between {ticker1} and {ticker2}: {corr}")
            results_2[(ticker1, ticker2)] = corr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, the [`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) method returns a *set-like* object that you can do set-like operations on:

```
>>> a = {(1, 2): 'a', (3, 4): 'b'}
>>> b = {(3, 4): 'c', (5, 6): 'd'}
>>> a.keys() & b.keys()
{(3, 4)}
```

From there you can pick the values from whichever dict you like:

```
>>> {k: a[k] for k in a.keys() & b.keys()}
{(3, 4): 'b'}
```

---

> ```
> {('CMS', 'LNT'): 0.8500276624334894,
>  ('CMS', 'LNT'): 0.7761431649456381,
> ```

This makes no sense as expected result, as you can't have the same key twice in a dict. Maybe you want this?

```
>>> {k: (a[k], b[k]) for k in a.keys() & b.keys()}
{(3, 4): ('b', 'c')}
```

Comment: I was not aware that you can't have the same key twice in a dict. I tried the using  result.keys() & result_2.keys() however I am getting the error message: AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'keys' I have added the code I am using to create the dicts to the question

Comment: So yes I am trying to get some result like this: {('CMS', 'LNT') : (0.8500, 0.7761)}

Comment: Yeah, that's probably not gonna work with [tag:numpy] stuff, which would have been important information to include…

Comment: Wait I am kind of lost, How can a dict be a numpy object ? And how does numpy affect the methods from dict ?

Comment: Well, apparently your object *isn't* a dict.

Comment: Okay so I think I am starting to get my head around this. In my code I am using "corr = np.corrcoef ...." and then results[(ticker1, ticker2)] = corr which turns my empty dict into a numpy object. So I guess I have to turn the numpy object back into a dict or find another way to add the Corr results to my empty dict

Comment: So I was able to solve It incase anyone runs into the same problem. First I sorted the numpy object using a simple if else loop also to reduce the size then I used  data_dict  = dict(sorted(dict_sorted.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])) to get a new dict with the sorted data. Afterwards I used the dict.keys() method to get only the keys and {k: (a[k], b[k]) for k in data_sorted.keys() & data_sorted_2.keys()} to get all combinations. Thanks @deceze for your help !

Comment: With output: "('CMS', 'LNT'): (0.8500276624334894, 0.7761431649456381),
 ('SWKS', 'QRVO'): (0.8507993847326996, 0.8306031102713851), ..."